# How to make transition from RootController to DetailController UITableview iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sdk, tableview, uimodaltransitionstyle

I have a UITableView with some Cells.
I don't use NavigationController, so I'd like to use UIModalTransition to Switch from RootController, my TableViewcell, to my DetailView, but want to  add a Navigation bar to attribute some actions, like Backbutton.
I don't want to use seguesTransition, I only used XIB File and any Storyboard.

I really don't know how to use the Modal Transition in TableView, anyone know how i can do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried

```
    [self presentModalViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

then you can set certain styles for transitions in it.

On the other view add a navigationbar and place a backbarbuttonitem and add an action to it to go back to your previous view.

Although why do you want to do it is unclear to me.
if you dont want a navigation controller on the first view, you can just set it to hidden.

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

and then in the viewDidLoad of other view you can do the reverse i.e

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
```

this is quite an easy way of achieving what you want with relatively less amount of code!!